# Edit many to many relationship EntityFramework C# correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to edit the contents of a pivot table in EntityFramework CodeFirst.

I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 with EntityFramework 6.1.3.

I have my models setup like this:

```
public class Post
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The post's id in the database
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The the categories the post belongs to
    /// </summary>
    [InverseProperty("Posts")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The title of the post
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The content of the post
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Content { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The moment the post was made
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime? TimeStamp { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The id of the category in the database
    /// </summary>
    public int Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The posts that belong to this category
    /// </summary>
    [InverseProperty("Categories")]
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the category
    /// </summary>
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see a `Post` can belong to many `Category`'s and a `Category` can have many `Post`'s

My problem occurs when I try to update a post and change it's `Category`'s.

Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
[ResponseType(typeof(void))]
public IHttpActionResult PutPost(int id, Post post)
{
    if (id != post.Id)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    var entry = db.Entry(post);
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;

    // Created at must not be updated.
    entry.Property(x => x.TimeStamp).IsModified = false;

    // Also attatch categories
    foreach (var category in post.Categories) // For the example, I assume all user input is correct.
    {
        db.Categories.Attatch(category); // This is not working
    }

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!PostExists(id))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

**The problem:**

Everything works fine: I can update the `Title` and `Content` of a `Post` no problem. But the `Post.Categories` is not updated in the database.

I have seen people updating many-to-many relationships by first getting the entity from the database and using `Include(x => x.Relation)` and then editing the everything inside that object. However, that requires loading a bulk of data from the database which is negated directly after. That seems bad practice to me.

**The question:**
How do I properly update a many-to-many relationship in EntityFramework, without loading unnecessary data from the database?

Comment: What version of .Net are you using?

Comment: @el_M I updated the question. I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1 with EntityFramework 6.1.3.

Comment: The junction records (`PostCategory`) tend to be very small. Usually it doesn't take much to load them and *replace them entirely*. That's the easiest way to deal with many-to-many associations.

Comment: Off topic: multiple function end points is considered bad practice, as is returning anything but OK from an action method. The request as such is always OK when the request pipeline has managed to reach the action method. Anything happening after that is not an HTTP error, and thus should be communicated by clear error messages (in an OK response) from your business logic. Makes your code much cleaner and easier to handle by a client.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your intentions well you should try something like this in your DBContext. It will create a third table named PostsCategories where you will have your relations between Category and Post.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
                       .HasMany(t => t.Posts)
                       .WithMany(t => t.Categories)
                       .Map(m =>
                       {
                           m.ToTable("PostsCategories");
                           m.MapLeftKey("CategoryId");
                           m.MapRightKey("PostId");
                       });
   }
```

**EDIT :**

So try this:
In DbContext:

```
    public void UpdateManyToMany<TSingle, TMany>(
        TSingle localItem,
        Func<TSingle, ICollection<TMany>> collectionSelector,
        int[] collectionIds)
        where TSingle : class
        where TMany : class
    {
        if (collectionIds == null)
            collectionIds = new int[0];

        DbSet<TMany> manyItemDbSet = Set(typeof(TMany)).Cast<TMany>();
        ICollection<TMany> dbColl = collectionSelector(localItem);
        dbColl.Clear();
        foreach (var keyValue in collectionIds)
        {
            var entity = manyItemDbSet.Find(keyValue);
            dbColl.Add(entity);
        }
    }
```

then in your Controller

```
db.UpdateManyToMany(post, e => e.Categories, post.MultipleCategories);
```

where post.MultipleCategories are id of Categories so you probably must add some field in your Post model.

```
[NotMapped]
public int[] MultipleCategories{ get; set; }
```

Comment: This is done automatically by the CodeFirst migrations. The problem is not that there is no table. I want to update data in a table that already exists.

Comment: This is a beautiful function and I appreciate the help, but *it doesn't work*. I've implemented it in the example I gave and there are *no changes* to the `PostsCategories` table. Here's how I implemented the code in case I made a mistake: https://pastebin.com/UbrUWG73

Comment: Did you try to debug this ? And are you sure you have Category with Id 4 ? When you debug make sure that entity in

        var entity = manyItemDbSet.Find(keyValue); is found.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you are going to get what you are looking for. In any case, you are going to have to load the entity graph into Entity Framework so it can track the changes.

As written in your example, Attach (which is misspelled by the way) will only add the object into Entity Framework's change tracker with a default state of Unchanged.

You need to tell Entity Framework that the record has been changed in order for EF to update the records.

If you *KNOW* that the provided category already exists (which is what I assume when you said "assuming all user input is correct") then you can use the following:

```
foreach (var category in post.Categories)
{
    // This will attach the entity and set the entity state to modified
    // Note this will throw an exception if the underlying entity doesn't
    // exist when the "SaveChanges" method is called.
    context.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

I am assuming you'll implement some sort of checks and balances to ensure the record exists prior to the above code, but in case you don't want to go through the trouble here is a snippet that should work for you. An "Else" block could be added to add the category if it doesn't exist as well.

```
foreach (var category in post.Categories)
{
    var existingRecord = context.Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ID == category.Id);
    if (existingRecord != null)
    {
        context.Entry(existingRecord).CurrentValues.SetValues(category)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Here is the link to [MSDN's website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx#Attaching%20an%20existing%20but%20modified%20entity%20to%20the%20context) over attaching entities. Hope it helps!